# Another way of saying ‘electronic devices?’

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I am looking to refer to a collection of battery-powered objects in a more colloquial manner than ‘electronic devices’. This grouping will include hearing aids, watches and torches. I mention, as ‘gadget’ feels too informal for these sorts of things. ‘Gadget’, to me, feels like a less utilitarian electronic object, and would be incorrect to apply to a hearing aid.  Any suggests welcome.

Comment: Battery-operated paraphernalia

Comment: If you assume that electronic is now synonym of digital (not that true for torches or headphones), you may refer to "digital widgets".

Comment: Just *device*. Isn't everything electronic now? ;-)

Comment: I would say that "electronic devices" is about as good as you can do, unless you want some cutesy word like "technologica".

Answer (score -1):

***Electronica***, perhaps - Electronic devices or technology, considered collectively (OED).

Comment: We definitely have [electrochromic windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass) already, but I'm not sure if [electrochromic sunglasses](http://newatlas.com/electrochromic-glasses/35842/) have hit the market yet. But even house windows like that would be "electronica" (as with your TV, PVR, hi-fi, house PC, etc.). I think OP is limiting his context to portable/wearable "gadgets". I might go for ***transhumanisations*** and assume the special subsense would always be contextually obvious.